# Generic but individual web-based packing list?

Tags: online-resources

I'm looking for an interactive web based packing list that list general items that you should put in your suitcase when traveling. I want to be able to check each item when I've sucessfully put it into my suitcase. It should be customizable so that I can add additional items and store them for later use.

A plus would be if some profiles are available, like for example: short city trip in winter, beach holiday, hiking tour, etc.

Is there such a tool available?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know of a couple of such tools:

1. [The Universal Packing List](http://upl.codeq.info/) - more what you want, you choose activities, accommodation, temperature etc, and it produces a list accordingly.
2. [Custom Travel Checklist](http://www.customtravelchecklist.com/) - claims to let you search by category from the 'biggest list of items on the net'

Answer (score 1):

[PackWhiz](http://www.packwhiz.com/featured) is one service I heard of a couple of years ago. The site seems somewhat stagnant now though. Basically, it allows travellers to share there packing lists for certain trip types or destinations publicly, and then you can use the same for your own purposes.